# Why do I get error "Runtime: b'no arguments in initialization list'" when running to_crs?

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas, python-3, pyproj

I have a geopandas dataframe that has POINT geometry in `NAD83`. I want to use `to_crs` to change them to `espg: 4326`. When I first bring in the feature class as a gpd dataframe, it shows no crs, so I use a function to find the source crs and then assign it to the dataframe (my understanding is that to use `to_crs` it has to already be assigned to a crs).

```
bldg_feat_cent_df = gpd.read_file(bldg_cent_cb_intersects_gdb, layer=state_bldg_centroid)
print(bldg_feat_cent_df.crs)
>>>None
bldg_feat_cent_df.crs = {'init' :'+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs'}
print(bldg_feat_cent_df.crs)
>>>'+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs '
```

Now that its in a crs, I simply want to apply `to_crs`. I've tried this a couple of different ways, including `inplace=True` but I still get the same error:

```
bldg_reproj = bldg_feat_cent_df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})

> RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

I had a similar issue trying to use pyproj and it seems like the 2 are related. Conda shows that my `pyproj` version is 1.96. How can achieve my goal and resolve this issue?

**Update:** As requested, here's the output when I run the above line:

[image]

Comment: It's propably because pyproj cannot find the crs data, for some reason. Can you show the result of `geopandas.show_versions()` (in case you have geopandas 0.6.0) ? Can you give some more details about your OS, how you installed those packages (new environment, from conda-forge?) Maybe show the output of `conda info`

Comment: It seems like the crux of this problem is related to the fact that it can't properly read the crs I am assigning it to initially:  '+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs '

Comment: Can you try if `import pyproj; pyproj.set_datapath("~AppData/Local/conda/conda/envs/geo_env/share/proj")` helps? (best check that the path is correct and exists, I might have made a typo)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is a pyproj 1x [issue](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/134).

I would recommend [installing pyproj 2+](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html). You can do this with [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html) using the conda-forge channel:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -n geo geopandas
conda activate geo
```

Or, you can install the latest version with python wheels:

```
pip install --ignore-installed pyproj==2.4.0
```