# Re-occuring errors in my JupyterLab environment because of instillation errors in anaconda?

Tags: pyproj, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I use python in the JupyterLab notebook environment through anaconda3 for my coding. I recently encountered a Runtime Error when trying to set the CRS for a geodataframe and from my research online it seems that this was due to an issue with the version of pyproj I had installed. Following [another stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338498/why-do-i-get-error-runtime-bno-arguments-in-initialization-list-when-runnin) online I ran the following in my anaconda prompt:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create -n geo geopandas
conda activate geo
```

However, now I am receiving a completely new error at the beginning of my code when I try to import plugins:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'pyproj_datadir' from 'pyproj.datadir'
```

At this point, it feels like I am creating more issues as I try to fix others so any advice on how to get everything working properly? Should I uninstall everything again and start over?